# E-mail display code (wordpress) approved in "About the author" field

Tags: php, wordpress

I use WordPress. I wrote a code to show an email on the **about the author** field on my site. email appears.

[image]

but I want this to appear after approval. I put a checkbox under the email section. (HTML only)

[image]

```
<input type="checkbox" value="yes">E-Posta adresiniz yayınlansın mı?</input>
```

How do I add php code to this checkbox? I have `author-bio.php` after adding it, how do I add code to it? What code should I add elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Use Wordpress Settings API to generate a checkbox and after that use an

> IF...Else

condition for checking the checked condition to approve.